# Why do we need Nil while creating List in scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have one basic question on List

I am getting the below error when I tried to create a List with cons operator

```
scala> val someList = 1::2
<console>:10: error: value :: is not a member of Int
   val someList = 1::2
                   ^
```

But if you look at below, as soon as I add Nil at end it works..

```
    scala> val someList = 1::2::Nil
    someList: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

I would like to know why is it Nil is needed atleast once at the end when we create a list

Is Nil a dataType? or empty element?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Exactly because of this reason.

> value :: is not a member of Int

In Scala, the operators are actually functions on objects. In this case, `::` is a function on `Nil` object, which is *actually an Empty list object*.

```
scala> Nil
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type = List()
```

When you do `1::2`, Scala looks for the function named `::` on `2` and it doesn't find that. That is why it fails with that error.

---

**Note:** In Scala, if the last character of the operator is not colon, then the operator is invoked on the first operand. For example, `1 + 2` is basically `1.+(2)`. But, if the last character is colon, the the operator is invoked on the right hand side operand. So in this case, `1 :: Nil` is actually `Nil.::(1)`. Since, the `::` returns another list object, you can chain it, like this `1 :: 2 :: Nil` is actually, `Nil.::(2).::(1)`.

Answer (score 7):

Infix operators whose names end with `:` are interpreted as method calls on the *right* operand. So `1 :: 2` is `2.::(1)`, i.e. it calls the method `::` on `2`. Similarly `1 :: 2 :: Nil` is `Nil.::(2).::(1)`.

The reason that the first one does not work is that `2` is an `Int` and `Int`s do not have a `::` method. The reason that the second one does work is that `Nil` is a list and lists do have a `::` method. And since the result of `List.::` is also a list, you can still call `::` on the result of the first `::`.

Answer (score 3):

`Nil` is basic building block for creating `List` as a **recursive data structure**. List is useful datastructure that provides constant time access O(1) to the head (first element).

List at it's bare minimum core, is built on top of 3 operations
`head`, `tail`, and `isEmpty`. `Nil` is singleton sub-class of `List`, so it is a special one-of-its-kind instance representing an **empty list**. The **cons** operator `::` is defined on List to build a list recursively, by prepending one element in the List.

See the definition of trait `List` and object `Nil` (highly simplified)

```
trait List[A] {
    def head: A
    def tail: List[A]
    def isEmpty: Boolean
}
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
    def head = throw new NoSuchElementException("head of empty list")
    def tail = throw new UnsupportedOperationException("tail of empty list")
    def isEmpty = true
}
```

Since any identifier/operator that ends with a `:`, associates to the right, `::` operator also associates to the right.

When you write `1::2::3`, scala tries to rewrite this calls as `3.::(2.::(1))`. i.e 3 becomes the receiver of the first invocation of `::`, which doesn't exist on any arbitrary data-type (Int in this case).

This is why, you always **build up** on an Empty List - Nil. Think of it as prepending each element, one by one over the empty List `Nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Any operator in Scala ending with a colon `:` is defined on the right operand.
So, when you write `1::2` means `::` should be defined on `2` i.e on `Int` which is not the case.

`Nil` is a Value of `List` and has a method defined `::` on it. So when you write `1 :: 2 :: Nil` it is evaluated as `(Nil.::(2)).::(1)`.